# Automate WordPress Install from python

Tags: python, wordpress

I have a python program that sets up a wordpress site on my server. It downloads the zip and unzips it into a directory, sets up the database and user, configures the config file. Now I would like to call the the wp_install function in wp-admin/include/upgrade.php and pass it the parameters it needs $weblog_title, $user_name, $admin_email ...

My question is how can I call this function from python? Can I do a urllib.urlopen and if so how do I call the wp_install function with the right parameters?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `wp_install()` gets called inside of `/wp-admin/install.php` during step 1, and after form data has been validated.  If you submit `?step=1&` ... (all of the other required form fields) it should result in calling `wp_install`.  So yes, you should be able to use urllib(2) for this.

Comment: I need to pass the parameters to the function called in upgrade.php

Comment: @CrabbyPete - right, so in /wp-admin/install.php (line 215 in my version), that's where `wp_install()` gets **called**.  `wp_install()` is **implemented** in /wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php.  So, if you need to pass additional values into this function, you need to do two things.  One, you need to update the implementation to accept the additional arguments you wish to pass.  Two, you then need to modify /wp-admin/install.php to pass those additional arguments.  If you're having difficulty with either of those tasks, let us know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Urllib is an option, but because your script is running on the local machine anyway, I would probably use os.system. That way you can execute the php script like from a shell. You have to look into the php file on how to pass the parameters.