# Looking for a cmd line alternative to using the Wordpress welcome page?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to initialize a new MYSQL Wordpress database, using CMD line on CentOS7, instead of going to the site URL welcome page and typing in the admin user name password etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new database using the console `create database dbname`.

Then download and install a new copy of Wordpress using the following comands on your html root folder:

```
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && tar xfz latest.tar.gz
mv wordpress/* ./
rmdir ./wordpress/ && rm -f latest.tar.gz
```

Edit the wp-config.php using nano or vim to specify the dbname, user and password for your newly created database.

And finally run the install script from your browser: http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/install.php

Comment: I have done all of that except the last part of going to the web link. That's the part I'm trying to find a cmd line option for. I want to install the site not using the install page.

Comment: type *php /your_wp_directory/wp-admin/install.php*

Comment: That just echoed the install.php file with no change.

Comment: Read what is outputted after the h1 tags. That's the content of the installation page that you should see on a browser. What does it says? (probably inside <p> tags)

Comment: I think you might be heading me in the right direction. I might be able to modify the php script to do what I need. That's after I brush up on PHP. I'm still living in the world of PERL. Will update later...

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if I can help you with anything that gets outputted there

Comment: I finally found where this was [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062513/bash-install-of-wordpress-without-visiting-wp-admin-install-php) I like @Broesph answer currently #3.